# Redirect::action() - Unknown Action Exception in Routes.php Laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I've spent two days trying to resolve this.

I have an app powered with Laravel 4, and there is a problem.
I'm using auth.basic in one Route, here is some code:

```
Route::get('/admin', array('before' => 'auth.basic', function()
{
    return Redirect::action('AdminController@createAdmin');
}));
```

I'm definitely getting inside of the anonymous function, but there is exception:
**Unknown action [AdminController@createAdmin]. **

Again, if I define route like so:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@createAdmin');
```

Everything works fine.
I think, maybe the issue is in the some scope thing...
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are really trying to acomplish with a redirect, but since the problem might be exacly it, you could just do:

```
Route::get('/admin', array('before' => 'auth.basic', 'uses' => 'AdminController@createAdmin'));
```

Comment: It i really strange, but I tried this solution and it was not working for me yeasterday. But now everything is ok! Thank you)

Comment: But I still can't get why it could not find createAdmin action. Interesting